# Are the Magic Items Compendium and Spell Compendium both 3.5e?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e

Are the Magic Items Compendium and Spell Compendium both for 3.5e, or are they based in 3rd version and need conversion before being used in 3.5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the [Magic Item Compendium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Item_Compendium) and the [Spell Compendium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spell_Compendium) were published for 3.5 so do not need any updating.

In fact both books take a number of earlier 3rd edition sources and provide 3.5e updates of the material.